# Do npm/yarn/yarn2/pnpm fetch package.json first, for parsing "os" field?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, pnpm, yarn-v2

There is [`os` field](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#os) in package.json.

So, do npm/yarn/yarn2/pnpm fetch dependency's pacakge.json first, then parse the "os" field(if exists), and download the source code only if os matches?

Or, do they just download every content (package.json+source) just all at once?

**Context**
I am planning to publish a package that includes some os-specific code(compiled by go). So I have 3 compiled binaries (for windows, linux, macOS). However, each of them has a large size. Thus I want to avoid naively include them all in one package.
Hence, I am thinking of separating them like `@foo/win32`, `@foo/linux`, `@foo/darwin`. Then letting a package named `foo` depend on all of them. And eventually, users install `npm install foo` without caring about their os.
Will this separation avoid installing unnecessary dependency?
For example, when `npm install foo` on linux, I want npm not to install `@foo/win32`, `@foo/darwin` under the hood.

Thanks.